# Android URL with https:// is refused

Tags: android

I am calling webservice function in android APP URL having https://. But I am getting error message that **Connection to** "https://something.net" **refused.** Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using API 23? Please, provide more info. Also, post your full Logcat to check the real problem.

Comment: You should use HttpsURLConnection: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Below method when creating HttpClient class object.

eg: HttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```